# Set marker to have unique id that's a string - Android Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

The only way to set a unique id (that's a string) is by setting the title the value, but the problem with that is the annotation bubble will pop-up.  I do not want the bubble to pop-up when a marker is clicked.  I need a way to set the marker using Mapbox's Android SDK with a unique id that's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return `true` from the onMarkerClick method, the annotation bubble will not be shown.

```
    mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(icon)
            .title("Testing")
            .position(new LatLng(51.0486, -114.0708))
    );

    mMapView.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MapView.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Marker tapped: " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```